# Another integration by parts problem

Tags: integration, derivatives

> If $f$ is a differentiable function on the interval $[0,4]$, find
>   $$ \int_{0}^{2} tf'(t^2)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
>   For which $f$ is the integral positive?

For the above question, I integrated using integration by parts. I let $u=t$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}=f'(t^2)$ so that $\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}=1$  and $v=f(t^2)$. Then using integration by parts formula I get $$ I=uv-\int\left(v\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)\mathrm{d}t$$ where $uv=tf(t^2)$ and I don't know how to simply the integral part? Is integration by parts even required for this question or do I have to adopt a completely different approach?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if you take
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} = f'(t^2), $$
You will not get $v = f(t^2)$.  You can check this by differentiating:
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f(t^2)
= f'(t^2) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} t^2
= f'(t^2) 2t.$$
Remember the chain rule!

However, if instead of attempting to integrate by parts, you hit the integral with a change of variables, you will obtain
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2} t f'(t^2)\mathrm{d}t
 &= \int_{0}^{4} f'(u)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2} &&\text{(let $u=t^2$, so that $\mathrm{d}u = 2\mathrm{d}t$)} \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{4} f'(u)\,\mathrm{d}u \\
 &= \frac{1}{2} \big( f(4) - f(0) \big). &&\text{(by the FTC)}
\end{align}
Thus
$$ \int_{0}^{2} t f'(t^2)\mathrm{d}t > 0
\iff \frac{1}{2} \big( f(4) - f(0) \big) > 0
\iff f(4) > f(0),$$
which gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = t^2$, then $du = 2t dt$, hence this integral is $\frac{1}{2}\int_0^4 f'(u) du = (f(4) - f(0))/2$. Therefore the integral is positive iff $f(4) > f(0)$.